# Ternary Madness

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a former coworker with a penchant for shorthand javascript.

Today, I came across this line and I have no clue how to decipher it.

```
var originalSrc = (wheelBuilder.ANGLE_VIEW == "front" 
                   && $(this).parent().attr("id") == "builder_wheel" 
                   && wheelBuilder.CAR_VISIBLE == false) 
                  ? $(this).attr("data-original-front-src") 
                  : $(this).attr("data-original-src");
```

Comment: Break it out into separate lines. It's pretty simple, which parts don't you get?

Comment: evaluates to false or returns an src attribute

Comment: I reformatted it, now it looks pretty simple to *decipher*.

Comment: Wait, you can set a variable within the boolean expression of an if statement?

Comment: @ErikPhilips you shouldn't reformat code in a question when the question is about the code in it's current format.

Comment: I'm kind of surprised your coworker wrote such long-winded code... `var originalSrc=$(this).attr("data-original-"+(wheelBuilder.ANGLE_VIEW=="front"&&this.parentNode.id=="builder_wheel"&&!wheelBuilder.CAR_VISIBLE?'front-':'')+"src");` is a solid 130 characters shorter...

Comment: @JackPilowsky yes,the whole first bracket evaluates to true or false, and whether its true or false it returns the data-original-front-src OR data-original-src  i dont get your question

Comment: @JackPilowsky - you can, but I don't think that's what's happening here...

Comment: @WesleyMurch Erik only added line breaks, making the code visible to people reading this question. If OP had done the same, he might not be asking this question.

Comment: Or shorter still: `var w=wheelBuilder,f='front',originalSrc=$(this).data('original-'+(w.ANGLE_VIEW==f&&this.parentNode.id=="builder_wheel"&&!w.CAR_VISIBLE?f+'-':'')+"src");` for another 11 characters of savings XD

Comment: Who knew ternary operators were so polarizing?

Comment: "Ternary Madness" is just a terrible title for this non-question. This is a single, simple use of the conditional operator. The only maddening part is that someone can apparently be employed as a JS developer while having *"no clue"* about how to decipher basic language constructs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the highest level, what you're looking at is the **ternary operator**. It can be confusing to people when they first come across it because it's not structured like a lot of other more familiar operators, but it's actually fairly simple once you understand its syntax. It's an assignment operator, and it's used as follows:

```
variable = condition ? "Value when Condition is True" : "Value when Condition is False"
```

So the part of the statement before the question mark, which admittedly looks at a glance like it's what's being assigned, is actually a evaluated as a boolean which is used to decide whether the value before or after the `:` is assigned to your variable.

Now for your specific code block: for all the `&&` conditions in it, there's only one ternary operator in there. Reformatting it into an if statement, it's equivalent to:

```
var originalSrc;
if(wheelBuilder.ANGLE_VIEW == "front" && $(this).parent().attr("id") == "builder_wheel" && wheelBuilder.CAR_VISIBLE == false) {
    originalSrc = $(this).attr("data-original-front-src");
}
else {
    originalSrc = $(this).attr("data-original-src");
}
```

That said, putting four conditions inside a ternary operator is still pretty poor form. The ternary operator is much more reader-friendly in simple cases like something along the lines of:

```
var message = statusCode == 0 ? "success" : "failure";
```

The fact that `?` and `:` isn't a particularly semantic set of symbols when they're stuck in between who knows what other code means that ternary statements can become hard to read at a glance very easily. The company I work for has explicitly stated in their coding standards that your code cannot pass a code review if you nest one ternary operator inside another -- it just lends itself too easily to creating nightmarish unreadable code.

Comment: Worth mentioning - this code is still full of anti patterns :)

Comment: Oh, I'm absolutely not defending it - but at least there aren't nested ternary operators.

Comment: yuck! ternary operators! If i'm forced to do that, i'd prefer LISP's `cond` construct

Answer (score 2):

Some pseudocode:

```
IF wheelBuilder.ANGLE_VIEW == "front"
AND $(this).parent().attr("id") == "builder_wheel"
AND wheelBuilder.CAR_VISIBLE == false
THEN set originalSrc = $(this).attr("data-original-front-src")
OTHERWISE set originalSrc = $(this).attr("data-original-src")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var originalSrc;

if ( wheelBuilder.ANGLE_VIEW == "front" && $(this).parent().attr("id") == "builder_wheel" && wheelBuilder.CAR_VISIBLE == false ) {
   originalSrc = $(this).attr("data-original-front-src");
}
else {
   originalSrc = $(this).attr("data-original-src");
}
```

better?

general ternary operature structure:

(condition)?(iftrue):(iffalse);

if you want to return something to a variable, the rule is just the same:

```
var yourvariable = (a == b)?(c):(d);
```